# Callable Statement - PostgreSQL - Multiple Out Parameters

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

We have a stored procedure in a PostgreSQL DB that takes multiple input and multiple out parameters. The procedure call from the PG Admin client works fine when we do the following,

call proc1(input1, input2, output1, output2)

However, if we try to make this call through a JDBC CallableStatement, we get the below error,

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement does not declare an OUT parameter.  Use { ?= call ... } to declare one.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(PgCallableStatement.java:205)
```

The PostgreSQL driver is "org.postgresql.Driver"

The Driver version is postgressql-42.2.5.jar

How do we make a call to PostgreSQL procedure that has multiple output parameters from JDBC?

Please find below the code snippet,

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://<<hostname>>:<<port>>/<<DB>>";

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user", "<<user>>");
            props.setProperty("password", "<<pass>>");
            
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
            CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("call schema.proc1(?,?,?,?)");
            
            cs.setString(1, "test");
            cs.setInt(2, 1000);
            cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
            cs.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
            
            cs.execute();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
}
```

Below is the sample version of the Procedure

```
Procedure proc1 is (input1 IN varchar2(10), 
      input2 IN number, output1 OUT number, 
      output2 OUT varchar2(10)) IS
BEGIN
output2 := input1;
output1 := input2;
END;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that includes a basic (simplified) example of the stored procedure you're executing and the Java code you use to execute.

Comment: Are you sure the procedure is defined in PostgreSQL database? The syntax resemble `Oracle`...

Comment: Yes, the procedure is from Oracle was recently migrated into PostgreSQL. The source copy for the PostgreSQL was not handy hence added the Oracle version of the procedure. The PostgreSQL procedure has no issues and runs fine when running from pgAdmin client. But, when invoked from JDBC it throws the above error. It appears to be some limitation on the Driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm testing the procedure call with *multiple OUT parameter* in JDBC with PostgreSQL 14.1 and driver 42.2.20.

Some care must be taken, as the ANSI call fails

```
cn.prepareCall("{call proc1(?,?,?,?)}")
```

with `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: proc1(character varying, integer) is a procedure Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.`  This may be connected with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53634135/4808122) answer

Similar fails also the PostgreSQL CALL `cn.prepareCall("call proc1(?,?,?,?)")` with

`Caught: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "null"`. This suggest a problem with the `null`*integer* `OUT`paramater.

I finally get it with a bit *hack* defining the `integer` parameter as `INOUT` and passing zero.

**Procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc1(input1 IN varchar(10), input2 IN integer, output1 INOUT integer, output2 OUT varchar(10))
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
output2 := input1;
output1 := input2;
END;
$$;
```

**JDBC**

```
// procedure call with two OUT parameter 
stmt = cn.prepareCall("call proc1(?,?,?,?)") 
stmt.setString(1,'x')
stmt.setInt(2,100)
stmt.setInt(3,0)
stmt.registerOutParameter(3,Types.INTEGER)
stmt.registerOutParameter(4,Types.VARCHAR)
stmt.execute()
println  stmt.getInt(3)
println  stmt.getString(4)
```

returns as expected

```
100
x
```

Comment: Similar answer using only [VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26110496/4808122)

Comment: Thank you for the reply/ answer. It was helpful. We made it to work without changing the OUT to INOUT but passing a default non null value like 0 or <<empty string>> to the OUT parameters and then getting the result set and iterating over the results.